# Send data from one component to another in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Hi I'm trying to send data from one component to another but not sure how to approach it.

I've got one component that loops through an array of items and displays them. Then I have another component that contains a form/input and this should submit the data to the array in the other component.

I'm not sure on what I should be doing to send the date to the other component any help would be great.

Component to loop through items

```
<template>
    <div class="container-flex">
        <div class="entries">

            <div class="entries__header">
                <div class="entries__header__title">
                    <p>Name</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="entries__content">
                <ul class="entries__content__list">
                    <li v-for="entry in entries">
                        {{ entry.name }}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <add-entry />

        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import addEntry from '@/components/add-entry.vue'

export default {
    name: 'entry-list',
    components: {
        addEntry
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            entries: [
                {
                    name: 'Paul'
                }, 
                {
                    name: 'Barry'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Craig'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Zoe'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Component for adding / sending data

```
<template>
    <div 
        class="entry-add"
        v-bind:class="{ 'entry-add--open': addEntryIsOpen }">

        <input 
            type="text"
            name="addEntry"
            @keyup.enter="addEntries" 
            v-model="newEntries">

        </input>

        <button @click="addEntries">Add Entries</button>

        <div 
            class="entry-add__btn"
            v-on:click="openAddEntry">
            <span>+</span>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'add-entry',
    data: function() {
        return {
            addEntryIsOpen: false,
            newEntries: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addEntries: function() {
            this.entries.push(this.newEntries);
            this.newEntries = '';
        },
        openAddEntry() {
            this.addEntryIsOpen = !this.addEntryIsOpen;
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sync the property between the 2:

```
<add-entry :entries.sync="entries"/>
```

Add it as a prop to the `add-entry` component:

```
props: ['entries']
```

Then do a shallow merge of the 2 and emit it back to the parent:

```
this.$emit('entries:update', [].concat(this.entries, this.newEntries))
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass in the key of name? The entry gets added but doesn't display because im looping and outputting {{ entry.name }}

Comment: @craigib The key? you mean like an associative array?

Answer (score 0):

(This was a comment but became to big :D)

> Is there a way to pass in the key of name? The entry gets added but doesn't display because im looping and outputting {{ entry.name }}

That's happening probably because when you pass "complex objects" through parameters, the embed objects/collections are being seen as observable objects, even if you sync the properties, when the component is mounted, only loads first level data, in your case, the objects inside the array, this is performance friendly but sometimes a bit annoying, you have two options, the first one is to declare a computed property which returns the property passed from the parent controller, or secondly (dirty and ugly but works) is to `JSON.stringify` the collection passed and then `JSON.parse` to convert it back to an object **without** the observable properties.

Hope this helps you in any way.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I got it working with help From ohmygod but I didn't have to use the $emit line. I've added an answer with how my code now looks and it works but I'd been keen to see if that's the right way to do it. 

I manages to pass the object by doing ```this.entries.push({name:this.newEntries});```

Answer (score 0):

So with help from @Ohgodwhy I managed to get it working. I'm not sure if it's the right way but it does seem to work without errors. Please add a better solution if there is one and I'll mark that as the answer.

I follow what Ohmygod said but the `this.$emit('entries:update', [].concat(this.entries, this.newEntries))` didn't work. Well I never even need to add it.

This is my add-entry.vue component

```
<template>
    <div 
        class="add-entry"
        v-bind:class="{ 'add-entry--open': addEntryIsOpen }">

        <input
            class="add-entry__input"
            type="text"
            name="addEntry"
            placeholder="Add Entry"
            @keyup.enter="addEntries" 
            v-model="newEntries"
        />

        <button 
            class="add-entry__btn"
            @click="addEntries">Add</button>

    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'add-entry',
    props: ['entries'],
    data: function() {
        return {
            addEntryIsOpen: false,
            newEntries: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addEntries: function() {
            this.entries.push({name:this.newEntries});
            this.newEntries = '';
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

And my list-entries.vue component

```
<template>
    <div class="container-flex">
        <div class="wrapper">

            <div class="entries">

                <div class="entries__header">

                    <div class="entries__header__title">
                        <p>Competition Entries</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="entries__header__search">
                        <input 
                            type="text" 
                            name="Search" 
                            class="input input--search" 
                            placeholder="Search..." 
                            v-model="search">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="entries__content">
                    <ul class="entries__content__list">
                        <li v-for="entry in filteredEntries">
                            {{ entry.name }} 
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <add-entry :entries.sync="entries"/>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import addEntry from '@/components/add-entry.vue'
import pickWinner from '@/components/pick-winner.vue'

export default {
    name: 'entry-list',
    components: {
        addEntry,
        pickWinner
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            search: '',
            entries: [
                {
                    name: 'Geoff'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Stu'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Craig'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Mark'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Zoe'
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    computed: {
        filteredEntries() {
            if(this.search === '') return this.entries
            return this.entries.filter(entry => {
                return entry.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
            })   
        }
    }
}

</script>
```